# SSO for O365 and SSRS running on Azure VM

Tags: azure, sharepoint, reporting-services, azure-active-directory, adfs

I've encountered various information on the topic of Azure and SSO and am trying to find out what I'd need for my specific scenario:

- I deploy SQL Server and SSRS 2016 on an Azure VM (native mode)
- I also have O365 including SharePoint Online
- I need users to be able to transition seamlessly between SharePoint Online and other O365 apps and the SSRS reports.

SSO with on-premise AD is a plus but not necessary. What is the bare minimum that I'd need for the scenario above?

- Azure AD
- Azure AD with Seamless Single Sign-On enabled (requires rolling out
  Microsoft Workplace Join to client computers)
- Azure AD + ADFS

Comment: Voting to close your question as too broad (1) and not necessarily programming oriented (2). Please consult with the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before asking.

Comment: I understand. I'd be grateful if you could specify why the question is too broad. I can take it elsewhere and reformulate it in the process.